# Unable connect to local webserver via secure ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, putty, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have problem with connection to the virtual server. I always get connection refused and I don't know how to solve it.

---

I installed bitnami wordpress on virutal machine(VirutalBox). This working great. I can see wordpress site in browser on ip address which is showed in virtual machine when it is run. So if I good understand, I have now a local webserver created on virtual machine.

---

I tried access to the phpmyadmin through the secure ssh tunel using putty as in tutorial:

Connect To PhpMyAdmin : https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/
I installed putty(ssh client), then I open it and start configured ssh tunel as in tutorial.

Precondition from tutorial:

- my server ip adress is:192.168.5.9
- bitnami default password is bitnami
- server is configured with public key
  (so i genereted private key by  puttygen)

---

Configuration ssh tunel in putty:

- I entered IP adress of my server in the "Host name" and saved session fields
- I also  add private key ppk which I generated in puttygen application
- Then I go to the Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels.  Enter 8888 as "Source port" , Enter "localhost:80" as destination and click "Add"
- I go to the Connection -> Data and Enter "bitnami" in auto-login fields
- Then I go back to the Session and click "Save" to save the configuration.
- Then I click Open to Open SSH session
- I get message **Connection refused**

The connection was refused, but I don't know how to solve it.

---

I checked:

1. SSH server is installed
2. SSH Service Status is condition failed - Condition check resulted in OpenBSD Secure Shell server being skipped

Comment: Doesn't the "SSH Service Status is condition failed" pretty much answer your question?

Comment: That, and as I have already commented on your original Stack Overflow post, you have obviously problems connecting to the virtual server at all. So please do not complicate the question with PhpMyAdmin/tunnel.

Comment: @u1686_grawity it is answer on question: why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Given your answer, that means the service wasn't running. Was there a part of the guides you followed that had you start the service?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what was wrong with this condition, but `sudo service ssh start` solve this problem.